# Calling a Lambda function from an EC2 without internet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

We have an EC2 instance which for security reasons has no Internet access. But at the same time, the code running on that server needs to call some Lambda functions. It seems to me these two requirements are contradictory since without Internet access, the code can not call Lambda functions.

Does anyone have any suggestion on what are my options without sacrificing the security aspect of the project?

Comment: Why do you need to restrict internet access?

Comment: To be honest, that's what is dictated to me. As far as I know, that instance has to be that way for security reasons. Please feel free to elaborate if you think it's illogical to have an EC2 without Internet access and expect it to call a Lambda function.

Comment: If it has no internet how do you access it?  Could it still send an SNS message?

Comment: We SSH into the only instance with Internet access and from there we SSH into the other ones.

Comment: Then it should still have AWS access - depending on the VPN setup you should either have the ability to call the Lambda directly or send an SNS message that the Lambda would pick up.

Comment: @stdunbar - most AWS services are accessible via public Internet endpoints, but an EC2 instance running in a private subnet may not be able to connect to those endpoints.

Comment: @Mehran - is the rule that you can't have _inbound_ internet access (so no public IP), or that you can't have _outbound_ access? If you can have outbound access via a NAT then you should have no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to reach the AWS API's generally without internet access. Two exceptions are S3 and DynamoDB where you can create VPC endpoints and keep it completely on a private network. Some services can also be exposed through PrivateLink, but Lambda is not yet one of them.

You can learn more about those here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html

Depending on your security requirements, you might be able to use a NAT Gateway (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or an Egress-Only Internet Gateway (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/egress-only-internet-gateway.html)
Those would provide access from the instance to the internet, but without the reverse being true. In many cases, this will provide enough security.

Otherwise, you will have to wait for PrivateLink to support Lambda. You can see more on how to work with PrivateLink here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-privatelink-endpoints-kinesis-ec2-systems-manager-and-elb-apis-in-your-vpc/

Comment: So they could drop a file in S3 and the external Lambda would pick it up.

Comment: That would be another way to do it. But that seems like a strange roundabout way imho.